# I try more to upload image but it provides error even I try more

Tags: php, html, css

Can anyone help me I am facing problem while uploading image.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $msg="";
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","man");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $fileName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
        $fileTmpName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
        $folder='images/';
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$folder.$fileName);

        $sql=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO manimages(image) VALUES ($fileName)");
   }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Uploading Images</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="uploadfile">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload image">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Error is Notice: Undefined index: uploadfile in C:\wamp64\www\ftest\index.php on line 5
and Notice: Undefined index: uploadfile in C:\wamp64\www\ftest\index.php on line 6

Comment: you are trying to submit the form without "enctype='multipart/form-data" it will not send the file to server without enctype attribute

Answer (score 1):

To allow forms to upload files, you should specify the right `enctype` attribute, by default it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which you should change it to `multipart/form-data`.

Try this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now you can access the `PHP` superglobal variable `$_FILES`, thus no undefined index error will be thrown.

Comment: @SalimMaulaie Glad it works. Kindly, accept my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` tag is incomplete, for uploading images it should look like:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Remember if you are using file upload control, you must set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`